# Rails: User has many posts, but only one post can be stickied/pinned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

A user should be able to pin a post/create a sticky post. But he should only be allowed to pin one post only. So if he decides to create a new pinned post/pin another post, he has to "un-pin" the old one (and an error message appears).

There is a simple association between my user and post model and the  post model has a column called "pinned" which is a boolean (true or false). This is what I've tried:

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  validates_uniqueness_of :posts, if: :only_one_pinned_post

  def only_one_pinned_post
    if self.post.where(pinned: true).size == 1
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

**models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**My questions**:

- How can I make it work that the user is only allowed to pin one post?
- Where do I put my error message, if he already has a pinned post but wants to create another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to ensure that there is only on pinned post, you might want to add the validation to the `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :pinned,  -> { where(pinned:true) }
  scope :without, ->(id) { where.not(id: id) if id }

  validate :only_one_pinned_post_per_user

private

  def only_one_pinned_post_per_user
    if pinned? && user.posts.pinned.without(id).any?
      errors.add(:pinned, 'Another post ist already pinned')
    end
  end
end
```

I wonder if it is better (from a usability point of view) to implementing it differently: Perhaps you should not tell the user that he cannot pin more than one post. Instead you can just save the newly pinned post and unpin any other post automatically. This could be done with a after save callback:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :pinned,  -> { where(pinned:true) }
  scope :without, ->(id) { where.not(id: id) if id }

  after_save :ensure_only_one_pinned_post

private

  def ensure_only_one_pinned_post
    user.posts.pinned.without(id).update_all(pinned: false) if pinned?
  end
end
```

The `without` scope is used to not find and not count posts with the given `id`. I use this in this case to ensure that the currently created or updated post is not found nor counted when looking for other already pinned posts.

Comment: Ah, thank you. This solution works great (and thank you for your other suggestion, too. I was thinking about implementing this user-friendly way as well). There is one more question: Could you explain what the scope :without is doing?

Comment: Sure, I explained why I use the `without` scope in my updated answer.

Comment: Ah great, now it makes sense to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take on your problem (simple and clean):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts

  # Helper to get only one pinned post
  has_one :pinned_post, -> { where(pinned: true) }, class_name: "Post"
end


class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  after_save do
    if pinned?
      # Automatically unpin any other pinned posts
      user.posts.where("id != ?", id).update_all(pinned: false)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks, I've tried your code and it works great, too!

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but I think this shoud work. Basically, the method `only_one_pinned_post` is executed during the validation and, in case the user already has a pinned post, adds a message to the errors object, which will prevent the object from being saved.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  scope :pinned, -> { where(pinned: true) }

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  validate :only_one_pinned_post

  def only_one_pinned_post
    if pinned && (posts.pinned.pluck(:id) - [id]).any?
      errors.add(:pinned, 'Only one pinned post')
    end
  end
end
```

The expression `posts.pinned.pluck(:id) - [id]` in the condition returns the list of ids of pinned posts, excluding the one we are trying to save. This way we will be allowed to modify the existing pinned post for that user.

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique index in the database on `(user_id, pinned)` compound field. It's the only way to **be sure** that user doesn't have more than one pinned post. All other application-level validations are not reliable (though you may/should use them **in addition** to the unique index)